# LiquiBase problem , class path resource [db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, liquibase

I am having a problem integrating liquibase with springboot. 
I have added the liquibase dependency in the pom file like below:

```
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

In the src/main/resources I have created the  folders db/changelog.
In the db folder it is located the liquibase-change.xml file that has content below:

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

    <include file="changelog/01-create-employee-scheme.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    <include file="changelog/02-data-insert-employees.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

In the folder changelog are located the files:

- 01-create-employee-scheme.xml

```
<changeSet id="01" author="xy">

    <createTable tableName="employee">
        <column name="id" type="int">
            <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true"/>
        </column>
        <column name="firstname" type="varchar(25)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="lastname" type="varchar(25)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>

</changeSet>
```

- 02-data-insert-employees.xml

```
<insert tableName="employee">
    <column name="id" valueNumeric="1"/>
    <column name="firstname" value="x"/>
    <column name="lastname" value="y"/>
</insert>
```

In the application properties file of spring boot i have made the configuration below.
application.properties

```
#Liquibase 
liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/liquibase-changelog.xml
spring.liquibase.enabled=true

#H2 DB 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:employeedb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

The error that is thrown when i start the spring boot application is like below:

```
2020-03-14 13:22:54.557 ERROR 5804 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Error parsing classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.github.rshtishi.payroll.employee.EmployeeApplication.main(EmployeeApplication.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Error parsing classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
    at liquibase.parser.core.yaml.YamlChangeLogParser.parse(YamlChangeLogParser.java:83) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.7.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:217) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.7.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:190) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.7.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.7.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:366) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.7.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:314) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.7.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:195) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase$SpringResourceOpener.getResourcesAsStream(SpringLiquibase.java:613) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.7.jar:na]
    at liquibase.util.StreamUtil.singleInputStream(StreamUtil.java:186) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.7.jar:na]
    at liquibase.parser.core.yaml.YamlChangeLogParser.parse(YamlChangeLogParser.java:26) ~[liquibase-core-3.8.7.jar:na]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

I don't understand why it is searching for file [db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml] when I have specified the property : `liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/liquibase-changelog.xml` in the application.properties file.

Regards.

Comment: I believe it should be `spring.liquibase.change-log=...". `liquibase.change-log` (without `spring` prefix) is deprecated.

Comment: Ervin Szilagyi is right and you also have wrong path to your changelog. As you wrote that you put your changelog to `db/changelog` folder then  it should be `spring.liquibase.change-log=classpat:db/changelog/liquibase-change.xml`. Btw `db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yam` is default spring's value.

Comment: Thank you, but I fixed the other mistakes.

Comment: adding `spring` prefix worked!

Comment: @bilak I have the same issue. How can I fix it? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75510595/cannot-detect-liquibase-log-file-liquibase-failed-to-start-because-no-changelog

Answer (score 33):

Try using the `spring.liquibase.change-log` property (and not just `liquibase.change-log`). This worked for me when I faced the same problem.

This solution is also mentioned in issue [CORE-3459](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3459?oldIssueView=true) in the Jira tracker.

Comment: liquibase.change-log is deprecated. It has to be spring.liquibase.change-log

Answer (score 7):

Spring `LiquibaseProperties` has configuration for liquibase

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.liquibase", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
```

So, in property/yml file should have sprig prefix for liquibase

```
spring:
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    drop-first: false
    change-log: classpath:db/liquibase-changelog.xml
    default-schema: public
```

make sure you have right indentation

Answer (score 2):

In the pom.xml file set the version in the parent tag 3.0.2. At this moment 3.0.3 does not work

Answer (score 1):

In my case `selecting` in `IDE` directory `resources` as `test resources` not like an ordinary directory fixed it.

`Intellij Idea 2022.1`

After that change `IDE` started to respect `application.yml` in this `directory`.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue. Replaced @ContextConfiguration in Test class with @SpringBootTest and it worked. Not sure why it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'd faced the same problem, but with application.yml file, the problem was identation, as mentioned above.

```
spring:
  liquibase:
     change-log: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

like this should work,

in your case:

try this:

```
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/liquibase-changelog.xml
spring.liquibase.enabled=true
```