# Exception for master.yaml while running Liquibase springboot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, liquibase, liquibase-sql

Ref - [LiquiBase problem , class path resource [db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60683101/liquibase-problem-class-path-resource-db-changelog-db-changelog-master-yaml/)

I am facing similar problem as above, however proposed solution is already there in my configurations.

Exception -
Liquibase failed to start because no changelog could be found at 'classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml

Here is my application.yml file. It already has spring: what else do I need to do to get rid of this error for master.yaml

spring:
liquibase:
change-log: classpath:liquibase/v2/changelog.yml
enabled: true

Comment: Have a look at this article [here](https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-liquibase-example/). Might help.

Answer (score 1):

from the above message `Exception - Liquibase failed to start because no changelog could be found` it looks like liquibase is unable to find the changelog file. I would suggest to add the changelog file oath in the properties file. Check out [this doc](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/creating-config-properties.html) for more details.