# Liqubase cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Tags: spring, liquibase

I don't understand what exactly is wrong with *Liquibase* because the path is specified correctly

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [db/master.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:195)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase$SpringResourceOpener.getResourcesAsStream(SpringLiquibase.java:599)
    at liquibase.util.StreamUtil.singleInputStream(StreamUtil.java:186)
    at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parseToNode(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java:71)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

application.yml file:

```
spring:
  liquibase:
    change-log: "classpath:/db/master.xml"
```

**EDIT 1**
Project structure

[image]

**EDIT 2**
Folder with compiled classes

[image]

Comment: please have look of this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60683101/liquibase-problem-class-path-resource-db-changelog-db-changelog-master-yaml/

Comment: @RaushanKumar I tried everything described there and it didn't help

Comment: @Drics And, does the resource actually exist? I mean. if you look for the resource in your application jar or `target` directory, is it there? Your configuration looks fine to me.

Comment: @jccampanero Yes, the resource exists and the path to it is correct, but liquibase for some reason does not see it. I added a screenshot with the project structure

Comment: Thank you very much for the feeback @Drics. Please, could you provide an screenshot of the folder in which your classes are compiled as well?

Comment: @jccampanero If I understood you correctly, then please look at the second edit of the post

Comment: just try with an absolute path :) ,from image it looks okay to me

Comment: Thank you @Drics. Yes, that is what I was asking for. According tho the screenshot, note how the resources directory contains `main/db/master.xml`. It may be ok according to your configuration, but it may be not. Please, could you try `change-log: "classpath:main/db/master.xml"`?

Comment: @jccampanero thanks for the idea provided, but it didn't help

Comment: You are welcome @Drics. I think the problem is related to your IDE configuration, something strange is happening... Just to be sure, copy your `db` folder in the directory that contains your actual class files, and try again. I hope it helps.

Comment: @jccampanero Thank you very much! It's really helped me!

Comment: You are welcome @Drics. I hope that the suggestion helps.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove  leading slash in your path

```
spring:
  liquibase:
    change-log: "classpath:db/master.xml"
```

Comment: It doesn't help